# Why does Negative binomial expansion have infinite terms

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, negative-binomial

Why does negative binomial expansion have infinite number of terms and not equal to the example given below

Why is $(x+a)^{-2}$ not equal to $\frac{1}{x^2 + a^2 + 2ax}$?
?

Comment: It is, but the point of the negative binomial theorem is to produce a _polynomial in $x$_, which that isn't.

Comment: Please learn to use MathJax to format math https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: It's like you asked: "Why does $(x+1)^{-1}$ equals $1 + x + x^2 + x ^3 + \cdots$ instead of $\frac{1}{1+x}$ ?"

Comment: @leonbloy; its $(1-x)^{-1}=1 + x + x^2 + x ^3 + \cdots$.

Comment: @JMP of course, thanks

Answer (score 0):

From [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), all binomial expansions have an infinite number of terms.

If $\alpha$ is a non-negative integer, after $\alpha+1$ terms the remaining terms are all zero.